# Entity Framework 6 - loading data from a 0:M relationship using navigational properties

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I use joins less and less these days, and rely on navigation properties as much as possible.

Here is a very basic schema:

**Users**:

```
Id              int
Surname         string
FirstName       string
```

**Enrolments**:

```
Id              int
UserId          int (foreign key for Users.Id)
EnrolmentName   string
StartDate       datetime
EndDate         datetime
```

A user may have 0, 1, or many enrolments related to them in the `Enrolments` table.

Now in a query, I want to select all user rows, and also the EnrolmentName column from their first enrolment. I like to keep my queries as lean as possible, and only select what I need to from the database. I don't like returning entire entities if I don't have to.

Here is my query (where I select the relevant data directly into a view model).

```
IList<UserVm> rows = db.Users
    .Select(
        x => new UserVm
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Surname = x.Surname,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            FirstEnrolmentName = x.Enrolments.OrderBy(o => o.StartDate).FirstOrDefault().EnrolmentName
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

The issue I have is that it works, but I think it should fail where I encounter a User which has no enrolments. I would expect the following line to complain that the `EnrolmentName` column could not be found on a null object.

```
FirstEnrolmentName = x.Enrolments.OrderBy(o => o.StartDate).FirstOrDefault().EnrolmentName
```

What actually happens is that it will leave the `EnrolmentName` column as NULL where there are no `Enrolment` records for that User.

I'd like to know:

1. Why this query works and doesn't cause an error for a student with 0 `Enrolments`.
2. Is there a cleaner way of writing the query so that it's still only 1 hit to the database, and still only selects the required subset of columns, and not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you should select only the properties you actually plan to use, thus transporting as few data as possible to your local process.

LINQ knows two kinds of statements: the ones that compose the query and the ones that will execute the query. The composers are LINQ methods that return an `IQueryable<...>` (or `IEnumerable<...>`), the executors are the functions that do not return an `IQueryable`, but a `TResult`. Examples are `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Any`, `Max`,...

You should always make sure that the executor is the last one of your statement, unless you are absolutely sure that the statements that follow the executor won't limit the amount of data.

```
db.Users.Select(user => new UserVm
{
    ...
    FirstEnrolMentName = user.Enrolments
        .OrderBy(enrolment => enrolment.StartDate)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .EnrolmentName,
});
```

I wonder if this would also work if you've got a User without any `Enrolments`. My first guess would be that `FirstOrDefault` would return null, and thus you would have an `ArgumentNullException` when you want to get the `EnrolmentName`

Another problem is that you first select one complete `Enrolment`, after which you throw away all Enrolment properties except the name. It would be better to select only the properties you plan to use and then use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = db.Users.Select(user => new UserVm
{
    ...
    FirstEnrolMentName = user.Enrolments
        .OrderBy(enrolment => enrolment.StartDate)
        .Select(enrolment => enrolment.EnrolmentName)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
});
```

Comment: Yes I think the second code snippet makes sense. Thank you.